# Print exim mail queue in html file

Tags: javascript, php, centos7, exim

I am looking for a script that will log/access linux servers and run exim -bpc command and print the output in html file. I want to monitor mail queue from different linux server in single dashboard.

I also want to set bg color based on the mail queue count, say if mails below 100 bg color for that cell green, if 101 to 150 yellow color and above 151 red.

Can someone please help me here.